# How to bind when an LDAP user doesn't have rights to browse the directory

Tags: java, ldap

We have a java web-application that allows authentication via LDAP. 
Basically, it follows this process:

- Bind to the directory with an admin user that has rights to search the directory.
- Takes a username/value and searches the directory for a user that has that username/value in a particular attribute.
- Binds with the user that is found with the password that was entered.
- If the bind is successful we grant login.

This works well, but we have recently come across environment where the LDAP user logging in, does not have access to browse the directory itself. This causes an error when binding.
(The admin user binds correctly, and searches the directory. It is only the final bind with the found user that fails).

Internal logging from the LDAP directory (CA Directory) shows that the bind function is successful, but as part of the bind process, the bound user is looking itself up.. which it doesn't have access to do. This causes the bind to fail.

The bind to LDAP is done with this java code..

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, createLDAPString());       
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

        return new InitialLdapContext(props, null);
```

Is there a way to stop the internal lookup from occurring?

Or is there way that I can validate a user/password without binding? ie. Binding on behalf of another user.. or comparing passwords manually (which doesn't sound great).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory is set up incorrectly. A user should be able to read his own entry.

Comment: This is what I said.. but they have another product that seems to be working with the directory in this structure, and it could be because of that product that it is in this form. Not sure if it is Java or not. I think they would be reluctant to change security just for allowing access from our application.. but that may be the only solution.

Comment: I suspect that the other product doesn't do a bind as the user, just as the admin, and compares the password itself: in other words it is incorrectly implemented. It can't be a requirement of the other product that users *don't* have access to their own entries.